# jq: how to only update data if existing?

Tags: json, jq

With dev version of jq, this could be done with `jq '.x.y |= if . then 123 else empty end'`. (Because bug [#13134](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1314) is solved.)

How can I do this in jq 1.5?

example:
in `{"x": {"y": 5}}`, y should be changed to 123,
but in `{"x": {"z": 9}}`, nothing should change.

Answer (score 1):

do you need to use `|=`?  If not could you use ordinary assignment?  e.g.

```
jq -Mnc '
      {"x": {"y": 5}} | if .x.y != null then .x.y = 123 else . end
    , {"x": {"z": 9}} | if .x.y != null then .x.y = 123 else . end
'
```

output

```
{"x":{"y":123}}
{"x":{"z":9}}
```

Answer (score 1):

With built-in `has()` function:

```
jq -nc '{"x":{"y": 5}} | if (.x | has("y")) then .x.y=123 else empty end'
```

The output:

```
{"x":{"y":123}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the following produce the desired results (whether using 1.5 or later), but there are important differences in the semantics (having to do with the difference between `{"x": null}` and `{}`):

```
if has("x") and (.x | has("y")) then .x.y = 123 else . end
```

```
if .x.y? then .x.y = 123 else . end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams could actually handle this quite nicely. A stream for an object will yield paths and values to actual existing values in your input. So search for the pairs that contain your path and update the value while rebuilding the stream.

```
$ jq --argjson path '["x","y"]' --argjson new '123' '
fromstream(tostream|select(length == 2 and .[0] == $path)[1] = $new)
' input.json
```